# java prevent class from overriding equals

Tags: java, interface, overriding, final

I want to use `java.util.Set` (and other collections) but with a twist: I want `contains()` , `add()`, etc. to call Object's `equals()` at all times (that is operate based on identity rather than equality more generally). I think I have a way, but it has big drawbacks. Is there a proper way to do this? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Here's what I've done:

```
public class OnlySelfEqual {
    public final boolean equals(Object o){
        return super.equals(o);
    }
}

public class Example{
    private Set<T extends OnlySelfEqual> set;
    //etc
}
```

The main problem I see with this (there may be numerous others) is that all Ts have to extend from a class rather than implement an interface, which is pretty restrictive. I think what I want would be something like a 'reverse' interface which lists methods that subtypes cannot implement (override). I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist though. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you define an interface, you are depending on the programmers writing classes that implement that interface to give each method the right semantics. All you can do is specify what each interface method is supposed to mean. In the same way, if you really want to do this I think it should be done by specifying the equals convention as part of the interface. It would be even better to use IdentityHashMap.

Comment: You are also missing `Object.hashCode` assuming a `HashSet` which should be using `System.identityHashCode`. Ian Roberts answer gets that right.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It's not always appropriate to trust other random objects. Indeed that's could bring surprises. Much better to be explicit locally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`java.util.IdentityHashMap` is a `Map` implementation that deliberately violates the `Map` contract by using `==` rather than `equals()`, so you could get a `Set` with the same behaviour using e.g.

```
Set<String> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<String, Boolean>());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's useful to know.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your objects inside a container which will implement `equals()` using the wrapped objects' identity:

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    // Either public (it's final), or private with a getter
    public final T element;

    public Wrapper(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (o == null || o.getClass() != getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return element == ((Wrapper<?>) o).element;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return System.identityHashCode(element);
    }
}
```

You then use `Set<Wrapper<T>>`, `List<Wrapper<T>>`, etc.

If you use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (which contains a lot of useful stuff complementing the JDK), you can directly use its [`Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) class (and [`Equivalence.Wrapper`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/base/Equivalence.Wrapper.html)) to get [that result](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html#identity%28%29), or other ones based on [different](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html#equals%28%29) [strategies](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html#onResultOf%28com.google.common.base.Function%29).

Comment: Another similar technique which is useful in certain circumstance is to use a package private final field in the base class as a key. This doesn't have the overhead of an extra allocation just to do a lookup and can be combined with the likes of `WeakReference` (why would you want a `WeakHashMap` that works on values instead of reference types).

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly, what you're looking for is:

```
T t = ...
((Object)t).equals( other );
```

I might be mistaken as to the syntax..

Comment: That would still call the overridden `equals()`.

Comment: This one has no sense, the same `equals()` is called.

Comment: Yeah, true, I was confusing it with multiple interface inheritance.